# Truncating a MS SQL Server Express table with one record takes forever

Tags: sql, sql-server, truncate

I am setting up a kind of test database in Microsoft SQL Server Express 2017. I have one main table with 10 columns, which is linked to 6 others, ie its primary key is the foreign key of 6 other tables.

I have populated this main table with just one record.

I need to truncate it - ie delete all the rows but not the table. I tried both `truncate table` and `delete from` but both take forever: after 4 minutes the query was still executing! I understand there are keys to check etc, but it's only one record. All the other tables are empty. This doesn't seem right. Any ideas what could be wrong and what I can do to fix it?

Comment: You would first be deleting all the child records prior to deleting the parent table record. Is the child tables all empty?. Do you have any uncommitted transactions in any of those tables

Comment: You can try shutting down the database and restarting it.  One possibility is that some locking is out of whack.

Comment: We need more. Please post your table schema and the queries you are executing. Which constraints did you create? Are there Triggers?

Comment: If you have foreign keys pointing to the table `TRUNCATE` won't work; which either implies you don't have them like you said, or you do and `TRUNCATE` doesn't work. If that is the case though, then you must have `CASCADE ON DELETE` enabled, which means a `DELETE` could well take awhile.

Comment: @GeorgeJoseph, I guess I must have had uncomitted transactions. If you post it as an answer, I'll accept it. I restarted the PC, and now "truncate table table_name" gives me, as it should, the error that it cannot truncate the table because of the foreign key. I am not sure why it didn't give this error before, and the query just kept running forever. "delete from table" now works correctly. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In response to the comment

It is probably uncommitted transactions, on your child tables.

You would first be deleting all the child records prior to deleting the parent table record. Is the child tables all empty?.

Do you have any uncommitted transactions in any of those tables? If you do then attempt to kill those sessions by engaging a dba.

Comment: I found uncommitted transactions by running 'DBCC opentran', getting the id and then running kill id.

Answer (score 0):

A table that has foreign key constraints can't be truncated. Either you drop constraint, truncate table then re-create constraints Or make use of delete cascade. here is a [link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/2a8f3acd-950f-430f-b7a0-4283213695e3/truncate-and-foreign-keys?forum=sqlgetstarted) for same.

TRUNCATE TABLE is a DDL command, it cannot check to see whether the records in the table are being referenced by a record in the child table. In case of DELETE, database is able to make sure that it isn't being referenced by another record.